# problems with logging in

Tags: 14.04

Just updated  to 14.04 through the software updates. Restarted my computer because everything was crashing, and now I cant log in. It sees my password and accepts it. But just doesnt open. What do I do.the details are. At the log In prompt I type my password and get failed to start session note. Everything I can see works like it should, but no matter what I do it wont open fully. I have gone to recovery and cleaned, repaired, updated,and checked the os. And the only thing I have found out of place is durring init. Start up. A file reading "starting reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure the remote queues are populated" shows a fail.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just had to reboot like a bunch to read it but in the init. Upload there is a fail. For the section saying "starting reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure the remote queues are populated". This wad the only fail I saw. Also I get the same error of failed to start session even if I log in as guest

Comment: Also I can see my normal background, move the mouse and use the tool bar. But some tabs like enabling wifi are not highlightable. I am able to and do have internet connectivity for what its worth.

Comment: Even the english screen reader guy works.

Comment: Now, just please add those to your answer please. Use the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/538470/edit) link.

Comment: Add what I just said to my answer? I dont have an answer, thats what im asking. How do I fix this?

Comment: My mistake. Your question. I apologize.

Comment: O.k. ill get on that. But in the mean time do you have any ideas or help on this issue?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

O.k. ill answer my own question here. first of all if there is a pop up for failure to start session. what it means is you havent finished the upgrade process yet. also you will need a constant and good internet connection, I recommend using a wifi connection that has already been set up on the computer or it wont be knoticed, and it cant be the sort that needs you to accept like starbucks. also as for code and tricks read all of whats on here some will work others wont. but you will have to make your own salad from the bar. I had to install gnome and then install desktop through the root.

Comment: I have similar problem and I highly doubt flakey internet connection on updates could be the cause of not being able to log in. What do you mean install desktop through the root?